# using custom fonts swing UI?

Tags: swing, fonts

I am learning Java and looking for some advice. I am using a custom font in a swing assignment; it's a executable `jar` file. Do I have to pack that font file as well inside the `jar` file while deploying to some other machine? It's an external `ttf` format font file that I downloaded from internet [from here](http://www.fontpalace.com/font-download/Helvetica+Ultra+Compressed/).

Will it work on all platforms? Has anyone tried this before?

Answer (score 1):

> do i have to pack that font file as well inside the jar file

### Yes

You have to pack that ttf file into your jar file.

> will it work on all platforms?

AFAIK, yes it will.